# How To Registering Protocol Handlers for Pywebview Applications?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm working on simple stand-alone web application to my work using [Pywebview](https://github.com/r0x0r/pywebview) and `html` but i have some problem when i want to launch  application in my system using `app://` protocol that i found in this [article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330937/is-it-possible-to-open-an-ubuntu-app-from-html) and facing this page for example :

```
Unable to load page

Problem occurred while loading the URL app://mate-terminal

URL cannot be shown
```

so, how to registering a Protocol Handlers to run my linux app in webview?

Comment: To the close voters: reading the post linked above reveals that `app://` is actually a protocol for Ubuntu's launcher.  The question has actually nothing to do with Python, HTML, or programming.

Comment: Thanx for your replay, simply i want to use `apt://`  protocol in my webview instead of web browser because it's work in firefox